# LDAP server unavailable. C# ASP.net

Tags: c#, ldap

I am new in LDAP coding. I developed following simple code to test my LDAP server but I get the error: "LDAP server is unavailable" . But I get the ping reply in cmd from the LDAP server. Any body can help?

```
   string domain= "ldaps://SomeDomainName.com:636";  

        PrincipalContext AD = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain,domain);
        UserPrincipal u = new UserPrincipal(AD);
        PrincipalSearcher search = new PrincipalSearcher(u);
        foreach (UserPrincipal result in search.FindAll())
        {
            if (result != null && result.DisplayName != null)
            {
                DropDownList1.Items.Add(result.DisplayName);
            }
        }
```

Comment: The prefix  `LDAP://` used to be pretty picky about having to be spelled in all uppercase ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to just provide the name. Remove the ldap from the domain string. For e.g.

```
string domain= "SomeDomainName.com:636";  

        PrincipalContext AD = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain,domain);
        UserPrincipal u = new UserPrincipal(AD);
        PrincipalSearcher search = new PrincipalSearcher(u);
        foreach (UserPrincipal result in search.FindAll())
        {
            if (result != null && result.DisplayName != null)
            {
                DropDownList1.Items.Add(result.DisplayName);
            }
        }
```

Comment: You were right. But now I get a new error: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: The server is not operational.

Comment: Try just "SomeDomainName.com".